# Overzealous @Constraints.Required enforcement on update in Play 2.0

Tags: constraints, playframework-2.0, requiredfieldvalidator, ebean

I'm trying to make Play stop complaining when updates don't specify required fields in JSON requests. The required fields already have values which I don't want to change, so I shouldn't have to specify them again.

stripped down model:

```
@Entity
public class Run extends Model {
    public enum Status { RUNNING, OK, WARNINGS, ERRORS, FAILED, CERTIFIED };

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    public Task task;

    @JodaDateTime
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime started;
    @JodaDateTime
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime completed;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition="ENUM('OK','WARNINGS','ERRORS','RUNNING','FAILED','CERTIFIED')")
    public Status result;

}
```

Based on one of the sample applications my initial controller action was:

```
@Transactional
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result update(Long run_id) {
    Form<Run> runForm = form(Run.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(runForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(runForm.errorsAsJson());
    }
    runForm.get().update(run_id);

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("id", run_id);

    return ok(result);
}
```

but if I just send `{ completed: '1341268791000', result: 'ERRORS }` it complains that `task` is required.

Then I thought maybe I could use [`Form.fill`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/data/Form.html#fill%28T%29) to fix it:

```
@Transactional
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result update(Long run_id) {
    Run run = Run.find.byId(run_id);
    Form<Run> runForm = form(Run.class).fill(run).bind(request().body().asJson());

    if (runForm.hasErrors())
        return badRequest(runForm.errorsAsJson());

    runForm.get().update(run_id);

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("id", run_id);

    return ok(result);
}
```

but that didn't help either. What's the secret?

Comment: After looking at the Play source I believe there's a bug (which I [reported](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/579-formfill-doesnt-actually-fill)) with `fill`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Form to insert/update any field, you can just also update the field 'manually' (*simplified sample, of course in your example you need to extract your someField from the Json*)

```
public static Result update(Long run_id) {
    Run run = Run.find.byId(run_id);
    run.someField = form().bindFromRequest().get("someField");
    run.update();
    return ok();
}
```

Comment: PS. Sorry for laconic answer, I'm going off right now, anyway I hope that will help you

Comment: @bemace: additionally check this post, maybe you'll find right conclusion there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/jYNlO5vDn7A/discussion and now I'm really off.

Comment: I don't see how this would work. `Form.get` doesn't take any parameters, and if I use `form.apply("someField").value()` it's returned as a String and then I'd have to do the conversion manually.